# How to retain selected option in dropdown list even going to another page in php?

Tags: php, dropdown

Assume that this code is inside a form tag with a method of post

```
  <label>Course</label>
                    <select name="course" class="form-control" id="course">
                        <option value="0">Select a course</option>
                        <?php
                        while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                         $courses=$rows['course_desc'];
                         echo "<option value='$courses'>$courses</option>"; 
                        }
                        ?>
                      </select>

<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block m-1" name="btnconfirm" >Confirm</button>
```

code in the second page

```
<form method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $_POST["course"]?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block m-1" name="cancel" >Cancel</button>
</form>
```

php code for the button is just only header like this

```
if(isset($_POST["cancel"])){
header("Location:firstpage.php");
}
```

how to retain the selected option even if I go to the another page, because when the 'btnconfirm' is clicked it would go to another page and  it would display the selected items, in between the dropdown list of course and btnconfirm I have bunch of dropdown list that is dependent on the dropdown list of course, the purpose of this is if the user misselect something he/she can click cancel and go back to the page and his/her selected items are still there I want the user not be bothered by selecting items he/she wants again

Comment: you'd have get the submitted value in your PHP (from the $_POST variable if it's submitted via a form), and use it to create the output on the next page, matching the selected value to the `<option` your'e outtputing, and write `selected` in there to make the browser know it's pre-selected. You can probably find existing examples of the technique online if you search

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
Ok, I miss-understand you. 
The point is on your second page to post your selected value from first into hidden input field. And when you press cancel that field will be given back to first page where you can echo it as selected option in drop down.

If you save this two scripts as test.php and test2.php and upload it to your server you will see you can go back and forward as you wish.

You just now need to implement this into your full page.

Working example:

**test.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="test2.php">
<label>Course</label>
<select name="course" class="form-control"  id="course">
 <?php
  $choice = $_POST['cancel'];
  echo '<option selected value="' . $choice .'">' . $choice . '</option>';
    ?>
    <?php
    while($rows=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     $courses=$rows['course_desc'];
     echo "<option  value='$courses'>$courses</option>"; 
    }
    ?>
    <option value='test'>Test</option>
    <option value='test2'>Test2</option>
    <option value='test3'>Test3</option>
  </select>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block m-1"  type="POST" >Confirm</button>
  </form>
```

**test2.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php">
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <?php
    $course = $_POST['course'];
    echo $course;
    ?>
    <input hidden name="cancel" value="<?php echo $course ?>">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-block m-1" >Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Comment: bro I tried your code its not working bro , btw in the second page i got button named cancel what it does is if its clicked it would go back to the first page

Comment: Edit your question with your other page included so I can do this properly.

Comment: Edited my answer with working example. @JamesSerrano